# Is it safety to erase the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder files

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

I'm using **Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS**, upgraded from **18.04**, upgrade from **16.04 LTS**.

Because some problem (not related with this question), I discovered I have a folder called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Where I can find a lot of files with references to older Ubuntu Studio versions (`eoan` and `bionic`).

Can I safely erase all those files?

Comment: Yes, it is safe, as in nothing will explode kind of safe. :~)

Comment: It should be safe, but to be sure please copy and paste the contents of the files in the question. The main things to look for are: 1. if the lines in the files are commented out, 2. if you still use any of these apps, 3. if you have other entries for ppas of these needed apps for `focal`.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1255215/edit) and add the new information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `/etc/apt/sources/sources.list`, and the .list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, work together to provide information to `apt` about software repositories and PPA locations. These files are used when `Software Updater` scans for newer applications, newer kernels, and newer libraries for your system.

If you're knowledgeable about how all of this works, then yes, you can manually edit/delete .list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. But because you're asking the question, I suspect that this is new territory for you. **So don't do this manually.**

I'd recommend using the proper GUI application, `Software & Updates`, "Other Software" tab, to manage the .list files that you see in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. There, you can examine, enable/disable, edit, or remove .list files.

For each entry, the goal is to have current Ubuntu generations in the .list file, like `focal`, **IF** the repository or PPA supports such a new version. Some still only support `eoan`, or older. So you have to know how to determine what each repository or PPA site supports. You generally don't want repositories or PPAs that support older versions than what you're currently running on your computer, as the software may not be compatible with your current system.

Any changes that you make via `Software & Updates` will trigger a reload of the software databases when you click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button. Any errors that appear indicate that you've made a mistake in one of your edits.

[image]